# How to make this jquery efficient? Performing function based on matching id name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, iteration, each

I'm using wavesurfer.js to build a page containing several iterations of code to control the play/pause of each of these. I'm going to have 5 or more waveforms following this same logic on the page, and I know this can be done a lot more efficiently than I've come up with to do it.

Basically, I would like the function to be performed on the wavesurfer waveform matching/associated with the button. So, ideally if the user clicks "#btn2" this will trigger wavesurfer2.pause() and if the user clicks "#btn1" this will trigger wavesurfer1.pause().

I know this should be a pretty simple thing using "this", ".each", or arrays, but I'm fairly lost on how to actually go about doing it and can't seem to come up with the right keywords to find the answer. Any help on consolidating this would be much appreciated! Thanks!

```
$(function() {
    $('#waveform').on({
        click: function() {
            wavesurfer.play();
        }
    });

    wavesurfer.on('play', function() {
        $('.btn').css("visibility", "visible");
    });
    wavesurfer.on('pause', function() {
        $('.btn').css("visibility", "hidden");

    });



    $('#waveform2').on({
        click: function() {
            wavesurfer2.play();
        }
    });

    wavesurfer2.on('play', function() {
        $('.btn2').css("visibility", "visible");
    });
    wavesurfer2.on('pause', function() {
        $('.btn2').css("visibility", "hidden");

    });


});
```

Comment: If what you have works, which can be inferred from the title of the post, this does not belong on stackoverflow but rather codereview

Comment: If you post your HTML there might be ways to do it without knowing the ids and button classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array similar to the following:

```
$(function() {

    var surfers=[
      {$el: $('#waveform'), surfer: wavesurfer, $btn: $('.btn')},
      {$el: $('#waveform2'), surfer: wavesurfer2, $btn: $('.btn2')}        
    ];

    surfers.forEach(function(surfObj) {

      var surfer = surfObj.surfer,
        $btn = surfObj.$btn;
      // element click listener
      surfObj.$el.on('click', funcion(){
         surfer.play();
      });

      surfer.on('play', function() {
        $btn.css("visibility", "visible");
      });

      surfer.on('pause', function() {
        $btn.css("visibility", "hidden");
      });

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this seems to do mostly what I'm looking to do, when the audio is playing the correct associated pause button becomes visible, but clicking either waveform does not play it. I can work around this pretty easily, but any idea why that wouldn't work when the button visibility does?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.play (wavesurfer.js:154)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

looks like it has to do with how wavesurfer handles the "play", but how yo have it written seems right. Let me scrape through this a little further

Comment: You will most likely want to do  `surfer.bind(surfer).play` otherwise surfers `this` context will be window.  Or alternatively use a function closure, `surfObj.$el.on('click', function play() { surfer.play(); }`

Comment: @Keith good point...I got carried away trying to over simplify. Answer updated

Comment: @Keith that works wonderfully, thank you for your help! definitely removes a major roadblock for me!

Comment: @charlietfl thanks so much, means a lot and helps me carry on. This definitely will keep the page expandable. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of thing I like using data attributes,..

Here I've used them to group the audio with the buttons, and also control what actions they do.

ps. Music from https://www.bensound.com/

```js
$("[data-action=pause]").css({visibility:"hidden"});

function setShowHideButton(showaction, hideaction) {
  return function () {
    const grp = $(this).attr("data-group");
    $(`button[data-action=${showaction}][data-group=${grp}]`).css("visibility", "visible");
    $(`button[data-action=${hideaction}][data-group=${grp}]`).css("visibility", "hidden");
  }
}

$("audio").on("play", setShowHideButton("pause", "play"));
$("audio").on("pause", setShowHideButton("play", "pause"));

$("[data-action]").on("click", function () {
  const grp = $(this).attr("data-group");
  const action = $(this).attr("data-action");
  $(`audio[data-group=${grp}]`)[0][action]();
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden">
<audio controls data-group="1">
  <source src="https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-goinghigher.mp3" type='audio/mp3' />
</audio>
<audio controls data-group="2">
  <source src="https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-memories.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
<audio controls data-group="3">
  <source src="https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-epic.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
</div>


<button data-group="1" data-action="play">Play 1</button>
<button data-group="1" data-action="pause">Pause 1</button>
<br>
<button data-group="2" data-action="play">Play 2</button>
<button data-group="2" data-action="pause">Pause 2</button>
<br>
<button data-group="3" data-action="play">Play 3</button>
<button data-group="3" data-action="pause">Pause 3</button>
```

Comment: This looks like a really good idea, and something I think I ought to get in the habit of doing... going to take me a moment to comb through this and figure out exactly how it's going on, however